# C function to print arrays of arbitrary data type

Tags: c, array, polymorphism

C is naturally clumsy at polymorphism but I wanted to avoid duplication so I wrote this function. But I'm sure there are ways left to improve it. Please not that for brevity's sake not all data types have been included.

```
void print_int(const void *number) {
    int result = *((int*) number);
    printf("%d ", result);
}

void print_double(const void *number) {
    double result = *((double*)number);
    printf("%f ", result);
}

/// Prints arrays of arbitrary type
/// \param array The array to print
/// \param length The length of the array
/// \param type The data type xxx of the array elements in the form of "TYPE_XXX"
/// \return 1 in case of an invalid data type
int print_array(const void *array, size_t length, char *type) {

    void (*function)(const void *number);
    void *cast_array;
    size_t size;

    if (!strcmp(type, TYPE_INT)) {
        function = print_int;
        cast_array = (int *) array;
        size = sizeof(int);
    } else if (!strcmp(type, TYPE_DOUBLE)) {
        function = print_double;
        cast_array = (double *) array;
        size = sizeof(double);
    } else {
        return 1;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        function(cast_array + i * size);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all this is a good attempt to provide polymorphism for print functionality. Few comments that might help:

I studied the print_array function and we can certainly do few improvements to it.

1) int print_array(const void *array, size_t length, char *type)

The type parameter is defined as char *. Since this function will support only a predefined types its better to have those as enum values. for e.g. you could do a typedef as

```
typedef enum{
INT = 0,
DOUBLE,

MAX_TYPES,
}SUPPORTED_TYPES;
```

2) if (!strcmp(type, TYPE_INT)) 
We can avoid these comparisons by making use of a Map like feature. Your current approach requires changing print_array function for any new type that we add. For e.g. tomorrow if you add support for print_char you will have to make those changes in print_array as well. Wouldn't it be better if print_array required no change. Ok so how to do it. In C++ there is a rule to replace conditional statements with polymorphism or maps. We will use maps here.

Since we already changed the type to an enum we can define a new struct which holds what functions to call for what data-types and the size of data-type as below:

```
typedef struct{
    void (*function)(const void *number);
    int size_of_elements;
}FunctionMap;
```

Now we create a mapping for data-types to function and store it in a global variable say print_map

```
const FunctionMap print_map[] = {
    [INT] = {print_int,sizeof(int)},
    [DOUBLE] = {print_double,sizeof(double)},
};
```

Now your print_array function changes just to few lines i.e. a lookup into this print_map for the type that is passed.

```
int print_array(const void *array, size_t length, SUPPORTED_TYPES type) 
{

    assert(type<MAX_SUPPORTED);
    assert((sizeof(print_map)/sizeof(FunctionMap)) == MAX_SUPPORTED);

    void (*function)(const void *number);
    const void *cast_array = array;
    size_t size;
    size_t i;
    function = print_map[type].function;
    size = print_map[type].size_of_elements;
    for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        function(cast_array + i * size);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I have added few asserts to make sure that the user passes proper values for type and that the implementer has add all data-type mappings in print_map. Now whenever you define a new print type say print_char you don't need to change print_array. Just add that function and its mapping in print_map and everything should work as it is.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Code falls short of "arrays of arbitrary data type" as it uses a `void *array`.  Portably, a `void *` works for a pointer to an *object*, but not necessarily a pointer to a *function*.  See C11 6.3.2.3 Pointers  for details.  C does not have a simple universal pointer type.
2. Invalid pointer arithmetic.  Although a number of compilers will perform pointer math on a `void *`, some as if ['twas](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%27twas#English)
    a `char *`, it is still *undefined behavior*.

   ```
   // void *cast_array;
   // function(cast_array + i * size);
   char *cast_char_array = array;
   function(cast_char_array + i * size);
   ```
3. Printing a `double` with `"%f"` will print about half of all possible `double` as `0.000000` or `-0.000000`owing to the many values smaller than 0.0000005.  It will also display large values with *many* digits, perhaps 100s.  Recommend using `"%.*e"` with sufficient precision.  [Details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359)

   ```
   void print_double(const void *number) {
     double result = *((const double*)number);
     printf("%.*e ", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, result);
   }
   ```
4. Minor: not a fan of ending a line with `" "` and then the `"\n"`.  Prefer just the `"\n"`.

   ```
   const char *sep = "";
   for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
     fputs(sep, stdout);
     function(state_variable, cast_char_array + i * size, i);
     sep = " ";
   }
   fputs("\n", stdout);
   ```
5. Expansion: Passing in the separator, or a state variable, as an argument like `" "`, or `", "`, etc. would be useful.  The return value of `function()` could be used to break the loop.

   ```
   int retval = 0;
   for (size_t i = 0; reval == 0 && i < length; ++i) {
     revtal = function(state_variable, cast_char_array + i * size, i);
   }
   ...
   return retval;
   ```

You may find [Formatted print without the need to specify type matching specifiers using _Generic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115143/29485) interesting.